# `google-drive` pattern of generated Google Drive folder ID

Tags: google-drive-api

```
$ gdrive list 
Id                                  Name                                       Type   Size      Created
1tqeNnGiZqy4EMj8p6d_LG7Js0aD9ao37   9b69f5168c0aa4bbe9cd5f1546169cf3           dir              2019-09-16 14:16:18
1ule-XdDb1JrvAEwqwN80JLs7LGuLGUxC   subFile                                    bin    5.0 B     2019-09-16 14:16:25
1ndFenMDcQbJFpQb3ScpaumdlITzf6Tc3   subFile~                                   bin              2019-09-16 14:16:24
1iTo4NUBe01tWODnFwT9SOQuVARd9nV85   example                                    dir              2019-09-16 14:16:23
1FDxjPDWLnP89miUTVjJ_0WMwdDDy_o5_   README.md                                  bin    96.0 B    2019-09-16 14:16:22
146N7bhF2Ev5kvJwprpedSu9EWkYPz1ic   run.sh                                     bin    197.0 B   2019-09-16 14:16:21
```

`Id` of each file is generated as 33 characters and contains non-alphabetic characters. My goal is to store a string value in a smart-contract as a type of `bytes32`.

=> Is it possible to compress `Google Id` value into 32 characters using base decoding?

I realize that all `Id` of listed each file starts with `1`.  So could I assume this pattern on the creation of the `Id`, where all of them starts with `1` and could I discard the `1` at the beginning.

Comment: Folder ID like `0B-#########################` had been used before. At that time, I had thought that the length and first character of folder ID are 28 and `0`, respectively. But recently, I noticed that the first character was modified from `0` to `1` and the length of ID became 33, when I created new folder in Google Drive. So I thought that when the total number of folders in Google side is increased, the first character might be increased. From this situation, I think that the first character and length of ID might be changed in the future. If this information was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike: As I understand Folder ID is dynamically changes over time and not based on a specific pattern. Randomly generated non-alphabetic characters like `-`, `_` also cause problems to convert them into `base58` format. I wish google-team implemented it based on `Base58 encoding` format like Bitcoin uses,

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize my comment was not useful for your situation.

Comment: It was useful @Tanaike